# upgrader in flutter don't have update on play store?

Tags: flutter, google-play, app-update, flutter-upgrade

I am using [upgrader](https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader) in flutter to upgrade the app from play store. Its redirecting to the play store if new version available, But The play store don't shows the update option, it shows the "uninstall" and "open"  button instead of "update"

I have updated the new version in pubspec.yml also.

Using like in main.dart file

```
return GetMaterialApp(
  title: 'Spindle',
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: UpgradeAlert(upgrader: Upgrader(), child: const Home()),
);
```

Comment: Are you properly increasing the build number on each release?

Comment: I have just made a old version of the apk that is redirecting to the play store but there is not  update option